# Ruby on Rails purge old rows from database after a given amount of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a ruby on rails server that maintains images for visual automation tests for a mobile application. A developer runs the visual automation on each pull request so he or she knows exactly what is going into the repo.

It has been over a month of production use and I am starting to think about how to remove old builds or old images so I can save space (and time for some of the each loops). The active record is as follows:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_suites
  has_many :builds
end
```

The migration looks like this:

```
class AddProjectToBuild < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :builds, :project, index: true
  end
end
```

I want to be able to remove builds if they are over one month old. How might I go about executing this in a production environment without touching the builds that have run in the last month?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: SQLite version 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the following steps to do this:

- Create a rake task which contains the logic and query to delete your old records.
- Schedule the task with a gem such as [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) or [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) on your production server.

Answer (score 1):

You need `cron` to achieve it. If your production environment is on `Heroku`, `Heroku Scheduler` is something you need to look into. It can help you run a certain task every day. In that task, you will retrieve all your builds whose `created_at`/`updated_at` or your own timestamp is less than `1.month.ago` and delete them.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using Heroku. I am using a Docker container and Jenkins for continuous integration. Cron does seem to be the tool to use though. I also have seen this gem called `Whenever`. https://github.com/javan/whenever. Have you used this before/recommend trying it?

Comment: That's fine. The principle is the same, doesn't matter which scheduler you are using. It is much more important to carefully define the task running in any of the schedulers.